# react-hook-form validate and save nested form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

https://react-hook-form.com/
I have a nested form, which has parent save and child save.

eg.

```
<form1>
   <input />

    <form2>
       <input />
       <button type="submit">Save Child form</button>
    </form2>
    
   <input />

   <button type="submit">Save parent form</button>
</form1>
```

Now, I want to validate child form and save it without affecting parent form, then on parent submit button validate parent fields and handle validation.

Answer (score 2):

The main that you have to do is prevent child form submit event from bubbling via `event.stopPropagation` and do your staff